# Replace keys of a hash with its value inside a specific group of a matched regex

Tags: regex, ruby, hash

I have an input:

```
input = gets
```

in which a substring of the form:

```
"本資料由(Name of a contractor)提供"
```

appears at different positions. I also have thousands of contractor names and their English transliterations stored in a hash:

```
hash = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
```

I have the following code:

```
input.gsub!(/本資料由(.+)提供/) {"\nThe following information has been provided by: #{$1}\n"} 
# => The following information has been provided by: (name of contractor)
```

To change a native name into English name, I can do:

```
person_making_announcement = /(The following information has been provided by: )(.+)/.match(input)
if Company_making_the_Announcement[2].match "key1"
  input.gsub! Company_making_the_Announcement[2], "value1"
elsif Company_making_the_Announcement[2].match "key2"
  input.gsub! Company_making_the_Announcement[2], "value2"
end
```

But this is very clumsy, and I need them in a hash anyways for other parts of the code. If I do:

```
hash.each do |k, v|
 input.gsub!("#{k}", "#{v}")
end
```

then all matches in `input` are changed. If I change the method to use `sub!`, only the first instance will be changed. I thought the following would work:

```
myregex = /(There is text here: )(.+)/.match(input)
hash.each do |k, v|
  myregex[2].gsub!("#{k}", "#{v}")
end
```

But it does not. I need to keep the regex since it is part of a substitution, and modification previously made on the input.

What would be the syntax to make the change only inside a specific subgroup in a regex matched to the input?

Comment: Actually, when I say, "...please tell me if I'm wrong." I mean "...please tell me if I'm right or wrong."

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be after the following, but please tell me if I'm wrong.

```
def replace_em(str, h)
  str.gsub(/\S+/, Hash.new { |_,k| k }.merge(h))
end

h = { 'k1'=>'v1', 'k2'=>'v2' }
str = "Now is the k1 for all good persons to k2 to their friend k11"

replace_em(str, h)
  #=> "Now is the v1 for all good persons to v2 to their friend k11"
```

`/\S+/` matches strings of characters that contain no whitespace.

```
g = Hash.new { |_,k| k }
```

creates an empty hash with a *default proc* that causes `g[k]` to return `k` if `g` does not have a key `k`.

```
g.merge(h)
```

returns a hash having the default proc just created with keys and values from `h`.

See the doc for the form of [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes a second argument that is a hash.